# How to Remove a Database Entry when a Link is Clicked

Tags: php

I wanted to expand my PHP skills so I read through a tutorial on tutorialzine. I understand the instructions presented in the tutorial. But when it comes to expanding on it I seem to be lacking a connection. My main goal was to simply delete a selected note when an a tag is clicked. However I don't know how to select the id assigned to the note to be able to pass it to my delete function.

Source: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sticky-notes-ajax-php-jquery/

Thanks for the help.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
require 'connect.php';
mysql_query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE id>3 AND dt<SUBTIME(NOW(),'0 1:0:0')");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY id DESC");

$notes = '';
$left='';
$top='';
$zindex='';

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    list($left,$top,$zindex) = explode('x',$row['xyz']);
    $notes.= '
        <div class="note '.$row['color'].'" style="left:'.$left.'px;top:'.$top.'px;z-index:'.$zindex.'">
            '.htmlspecialchars($row['text']).'
            <div class="author">'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).'</div>
            <span class="data">'.$row['id'].'</span>
            <a id="remove_note" href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteNote('<? echo $row['id']; ?>');">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>';
}
function deleteNote(id){
    $sql="DELETE FROM notes WHERE id='$rows['id']'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("Error when tryin to delete note.");
}
?>
```

**Update:**

I've been playing around with this and the answers that both Andrew and sachleen have provided. And ill plan to work on an AJAX alternative since you've mentioned the whole SQL Injection issue. But I am still having issues with passing the id to the remove.php file. I believe is has to do with  how $notes is creating the information from the DB.

I say this because I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/avonamyd/public_html/projects_php/sticky_notes/demo.php on line 24

And that is only when I include the code as is from sachleen. But when I update it to account for the single quotes I have the following code. The id is present and is passed to the remove.php file but I am still getting an error. This is when I use my code or what you've provided.

```
        $notes.= '
        <div class="note '.$row['color'].'" style="left:'.$left.'px;top:'.$top.'px;z-index:'.$zindex.'">
            '.htmlspecialchars($row['text']).'
            <div class="author">'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).'</div>
            <span class="data">'.$row['id'].'</span>
            <a id="remove_note" target="_blank" href="remove.php?id='.$row['id'].'">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>';
```

Below is what I currently have in my remove.php file:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$_GET['id'];
function deleteNote($id){
    $sql="DELETE FROM notes WHERE id='$id'";
}
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("Error when tryin to delete note.");
```

?>

**Update**

I've added in additional echo lines throughout the remove.php and this is what I am coming up with.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$_GET['id'];
echo  $id; --doesnt show
function deleteNote($id){
    echo "hello"; --doesnt show
    $sql="SELECT FROM notes WHERE id='$id'";
}
echo  'hello2'; --shows
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die("Error when tryin to delete note.");
```

?>

**Update:** 
Thank you for everyone's help with this project I've finally gotten the concepts to click in my head after some tinkering around. I will post the functional code below for anyone else that stumbles upon this code. =D
Thx Everyone!

**demo.php**

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
require 'connect.php';
mysql_query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE id>3 AND dt<SUBTIME(NOW(),'0 1:0:0')");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY id DESC");

$notes = '';
$left='';
$top='';
$zindex='';

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    list($left,$top,$zindex) = explode('x',$row['xyz']);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $notes.= '
        <div class="note '.$row['color'].'" style="left:'.$left.'px;top:'.$top.'px;z-index:'.$zindex.'">
            '.htmlspecialchars($row['text']).'
            <div class="author">'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).'</div>
            <span class="data">'.$row['id'].'</span>
            <a id="remove_note" target="_blank" href="remove.php?id='.$row['id'].'">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>';
}
```

**remove.php**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$sql="DELETE FROM notes WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Unable to delete database entry.");
```

?>

Comment: In the updated version of the code, you have a `deleteNote` function, but it doesn't ever get called. Also , you are trying to use a variable, `$id` that you have not assigned. I would say you should get rid of the function `deleteNote` and assign `$id = $_GET['id']` Keep in mind that _ajax does not protect you from sql injection_ - You will still need to sanitize the id that is passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to mix JavaScript and PHP. You cannot call the deleteNote() function when your link is clicked because it is a PHP function. There are a couple of ways to go about calling the PHP script to delete the note:

Use something like the following:

```
<?php
// ...
$id_to_delete = $_GET['id'];
if( isset($id_to_delete) ) {
    $sql="DELETE FROM notes WHERE id='$id_to_delete'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("Error when tryin to delete note.");
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY id DESC");

//...

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
   //...
   echo '<a id="remove_note" href="CURRENT_SCRIPT_URL?id=' . $id_to_delete . '">X</a>';
   //...
}
?>
```

Or you could create a second script that deletes a row from the database based on the data that you pass to it and use ajax (I would recommend using jQuery for ajax functionality) to call that script with the id of the item to delete.

Remember that anyone could call your script with a GET parameter and delete a record from the database (or worse, perform an SQL injection attack), so make sure that you have some sort of safeguard in place unless you want all of your records wiped out!

Comment: I've made an update to the post, I don't know if this makes a different but I also updated my js file so that when new notes are created they can be removed as well. But I don't think that's what's causing the record to not be deleted from the DB.

Answer (score 3):

You can't `onclick` a PHP function. You're mixing JavaScript with PHP. I would do this:

```
<a id="remove_note" href="remove.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Remove</a>
```

And then on `remove.php` get the ID using `$_GET['id']` and pass that into the `DELETE` query.

Comment: actually it's worse than confusing PHP with JS - it's confusing client-side with server-side! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 options.

1) make an `<a href="another_php_script.php?delete=true">` (or similar), then run the delete script. (then header back to the same page you were on).

This is because you cannot run an onClick php function, you have to redirect to the other page.

2) You can use the onclick function to call an AJAX script, and execute the deleting PHP script from the page you're on - without redirecting.

Option 1 is the easy option, Option 2 is the better option to learn from.

Comment: I can agree that using AJAX would be a better option and I do plan on updating it to use it. But I want to make sure I understand how PHP passes information. In any case I have updated the code to use a separate file to delete the record. However I am now running into the problem that the records aren't being deleted. Is it because the file isn't connecting to my DB?

Comment: it could be, are you including a file that is meant to be connecting?

if so, run a test SQL statement and echo results. just down to debugging now.

And to be sure you know how PHP Passes information - it's just GET and POST parameters connecting to a URL.

Comment: Yes, connect.php does work as I would not be able to access the DB to pull information from it. The file is also in the root with the new remove.php file so it's not a file path issue. =/

Comment: ok, if you're running the same delete query as above, change "DELETE" to "SELECT * ", then echo the results. Is there any?

Comment: I've updated the query and I didn't get anything, I've also  added in echo statements and the entire delete note function is skipped. If I echo hi before the function it appears so that means that the variable isn't being passed into the function. But this is where I have no clue since $_GET is requesting the id param from the URL, right?

Comment: alrighty. echo `$id_to_delete`, make sure its the same as 'BLAH' in `?id=BLAH`.

check you're requiring the right file dir. best way you can do this is:

`require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . 'remove.php')`;

Basically that will grab whatever directory the current file is in, and `require_once()` it. with require, if it can't find the file, it will stop your page from loading (fatal error).

Comment: Thanks for you're help I got it to work, I will now work on transferring everything over to using AJAX.